# depois de criar um arquivo(.txt) iterar a partir de uma linha que nao seja o inicio

Tags: python

É o seguinte eu tenho um arquivo de entrada(.txt) que é o seguinte:

```
9
branco
preto
azul
verde
rosa
amarelo
vermelho
cinza
lilas
OHLEMREVU
BBRANCOZA
SRAMSUPAO
AABAPOTZZ
LNZROERNU
IUIEPDOII
LOLLORACA
ITMOTERPP
LIEAZVYUU
```

e a partir deste eu quero iterar apenas na parte

```
OHLEMREVU
BBRANCOZA
SRAMSUPAO
AABAPOTZZ
LNZROERNU
IUIEPDOII
LOLLORACA
ITMOTERPP
LIEAZVYUU
```

para isso pensei usei  usar um for mas sempre que faço isso ele "seleciona" todas as linhas" em vez da parte pretendida. Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOPT. Sua pergunta não está clara. As palavras no arquivo estão assim mesmo todas juntas, ou uma em cada linha? Como você fez o seu código (edite a pergunta e poste o trecho relevante). Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e, principalmente, leia [ask].

Comment: De qualquer forma vai ter que iterar linha a linha. Pega o valor da primeira (que eu suponho que seja quantas palavras são) e poe numa lista (com um if contador < numero da 1a linha). Se a condição do IF foi atingida, o que vier depois é o tabuleiro do seu caça-palavras. Em resumo: pega 1a linha, converte para numérico. vai pegando as linhas seguintes e incrementando um contador. enquanto o contador for menor ou igual o valor inicial, guarda na lista de palavras, senão, guarda no tabuleiro.

Comment: Sim, o arquivo é como está agora(cada palavra por linha).

Comment: Toshiyuki, seria legal você clicar em [edit] e acrescentar o código que tentou no post, fica mais fácil para quem for responder usar como base para localizar o problema ou propor solução..

Comment: Só mais uma questão se eu quiser em tuplos(tuplas) em vez de listas como faria?

Comment: Eu ainda estou na parte inicial mas quando acabar de fazer a função procurar_palavras eu posto aqui.

Comment: @Toshiyuki poste essa parte inicial na pergunta, assim o pessoal pode postar uma resposta oficial. Assim, resolve essa parte inicial, aí na hora de procurar abre uma pergunta separada partindo do código já resolvido. O ideal aqui é sempre dividir o problema em pequenas partes, e resolver uma por vez em cada pergunta, de maneira objetiva. Clique em [edit] e ponha o código, mesmo que ainda não funcione como quer, e explique com mais detalhes, aí a chance de uma resposta legal aumenta, em vez de ficarmos resolvendo nos comentários.

Comment: Seria bom se na pergunta você deixasse claro que isso são palavras cruzadas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supondo que a sua primeira linha tenha o número de linhas a ignorar (você não deixou isso exatamente claro), basta fazer assim:

```
try:
    file = open('teste.txt', 'r')

    # Lê o número de linhas a ignorar
    n = int(file.readline().strip())

    # Ignora as n-primeira linhas
    for i in range(n):
        file.readline()

    # itera sobre as demais linhas, como desejado
    for line in file:
        print(line.strip()) # O strip serve para remover a terminação de linha ('\n')
except:
    print('Oops! Não foi possível ler o arquivo de entrada.')
else:
    file.close()
```

Resultado:

```
> teste.py
OHLEMREVU
BBRANCOZA
SRAMSUPAO
AABAPOTZZ
LNZROERNU
IUIEPDOII
LOLLORACA
ITMOTERPP
LIEAZVYUU
```

Comment: @Miguel Bem observado Miguel. Obrigado. Eu fiz a correção sugerida. :)

Comment: De nada Luiz, boa resposta

Comment: +1, creio que para o que foi perguntado, é uma solução que mostra todos os detalhes envolvidos. Creio que para os próximos passos (como a questão das tuplas), o autor pode fazer novas perguntas separadas e específicas se precisar de ajuda da comunidade, partindo desta solução depois de ajustada para o caso real dele. Inclusive, com esta resposta ele já consegue pegar a lista de palavras no primeiro for e o "tabuleiro" no segundo